# Alert box not repeating and input checking not working

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a small Android App for personal stuff and have two problem with my code now:

1. The code should execute the following until

> isAlarm == false;

```
                do {
                (new BTask(context)).execute();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } while (isAlarm);
```

But it only does this once.

2. I want it to close the dialog box only it the correct password is entered, but it closes it everytime and not executing the command:

> isAlarm = false;

I know, the code is not very beautiful, but I'm still learning. =)

```
package top.sysop.myapplication;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.media.ToneGenerator;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "";
    public static Button btn1;
    public static Button btn2;
    public static Button btn3;
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    boolean isAlarm;
    private String m_Text = "";
    Context context;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.context=this;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dialogevent3();
    }
    public void dialogevent3() {
        int i=1;
        btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dial3);
        btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Diebstahl!");
// Set up the input
                final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
// Specify the type of input expected; this, for example, sets the input as a password, and will mask the text
                input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
                builder.setView(input);
// Set up the buttons
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        m_Text = input.getText().toString();
                        if (m_Text.equals("pass"))
                        {
                            //end
                            isAlarm = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //repeat
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            dialogevent3();
                        }
                    }
                });
                do {
                    (new BTask(context)).execute();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } while (isAlarm);
            //    alert.show();
                builder.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: please include the code within the question, the pastebin link can go down leaving the question without context, the text within the question can not

Comment: @SomeJavaGuy thanks for your input, I changed it

Comment: the task does repeat. but that what you want to repeat, only is triggered by a ClickEvent

Comment: @Stultuske where do I have to write it then?
It should only start when I click on the Button (which is triggering the dialogevent()) and then repeating until I enter the correct passcode

Answer (score 3):

You're not initialzing the value of **isAlarm** so its containing the default value that is **false**.
there are some changes like

initialize `boolean isAlarm = true`

change `while (isAlarm)` to `while (!isAlarm)`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this continuous checking using TextWatcher and runnable.

custom_layout_for_dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:gravity="center">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter Password..."/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:hint="Password here"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

call this method to open a custom dialog from your Activity

```
public void customDialog()
    {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_layout_for_dialog);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        EditText edt_password= (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        edt_password.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
              //write all your operations here
                String m_Text=s.toString();
                if (m_Text.equals("pass"))
                {
                    //end
                    isAlarm = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    //repeat
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    dialogevent3();
                }
            }
        });
        //This handler checks for isAlarm for every 300ms
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (isAlarm){
                    (new BTask(context)).execute();
                }
            }
        },300);
        dialog.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys
I've solved it using the following code:

> MainActivity.java

```
package top.sysop.myapplication;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.media.ToneGenerator;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "";
    public static Button btn1;
    public static Button btn2;
    public static Button btn3;
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    public static boolean isAlarm;
    private String m_Text = "";
    Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.context=this;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dialogevent1();
        dialogevent2();
        dialogevent3();
    }

    public void dialogevent1() {
        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dial1);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                AlertDialog.Builder altdial = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                altdial.setMessage("Bitte geben Sie mich bei der Kasse ab.").setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                dialogInterface.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alert = altdial.create();
                alert.setTitle("xxx");
                alert.show();
            }
        });
    }

    public void dialogevent2() {
        btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dial2);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                AlertDialog.Builder altdial = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                altdial.setMessage("Bitte geben Sie mich sofort bei der Kasse ab!").setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                dialogInterface.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alert = altdial.create();
                alert.setTitle("xxx");
                alert.show();
            }
        });
    }

    public void dialogevent3() {
        isAlarm = true;
        btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dial3);
        btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                buildDialog();




/*                                AlertDialog.Builder altdial = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                altdial.setMessage("Sie begehen Diebstahl!").setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                isAlarm = false;
                                dialogInterface.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alert = altdial.create();
                alert.setTitle("xxx");*/





                //    alert.show();

            }

        });
    }
    private void buildDialog() {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Diebstahl!");

// Set up the input
        final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
// Specify the type of input expected; this, for example, sets the input as a password, and will mask the text
        input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
        builder.setView(input);

// Set up the buttons
        builder.setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                m_Text = input.getText().toString();
                if (m_Text.equals("pass"))
                {
                    //end
                    isAlarm = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    //repeat
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    buildDialog();
                    input.setText("");
                }
            }
        });

        (new BTask(context)).execute();

        builder.show();
    }


}
```

and

> BTask.java

```
package top.sysop.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.ToneGenerator;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Vibrator;

/**
 * Created by Szalewicz on 22.11.2017.
 */

public class BTask extends AsyncTask {
    Context context;

    public BTask() {
    }

    public BTask(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override

    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
        final Vibrator v = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        final ToneGenerator toneGen1 = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);


        do {
            v.vibrate(500);
            toneGen1.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_MED_SSL, 500);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } while (MainActivity.isAlarm);


        //for (int faktor = 1; faktor <= 10; faktor ++) {
        v.vibrate(500);
        toneGen1.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_MED_SSL, 500);
        //    try {
        //       Thread.sleep(500);
        //    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        //        e.printStackTrace();
        //    }
        //}
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now it's doing what I want =)